# Predicate logic describing a function that is not onto.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to understand how to write predicate logic describing a function that is not onto.

A function is onto if every element in the codomain gets mapped to by some element in the domain using the given function.

---

The function $\: f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \: f(x)=\lceil x\rceil$ is *not* onto; All codomain elements are not mapped to.

To my best understanding the predicate logic for this function in relation to being onto would look like:

$$ \forall x\neg\exists y\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)=y\not=noninteger\} $$

- **Is this the correct form?**
- **How would I write "y can not be a fraction" mathematically?**

Answer (score 2):

$f$ being onto means $\forall y \exists x : f(x)=y$. $f$ being not onto simply is one of the equivalent $\lnot(\forall y \exists x f(x)=y)$ or $\exists y :\lnot (\exists x : f(x)=y)$ or $\exists y\forall x: f(x)\neq y$.

To say $y$ is not a fraction is $\forall p\in\mathbb{Z},\forall q\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:p/q\neq y$. This $y$ shows that the function $(x,y)\mapsto x/y$ on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say the function is not onto (ignoring what $f$ is), you can say $\exists x \lnot \exists y f(y)=x$, which just says there is some number $x$ that is not the image of any $y$.  To say $y$ is an integer you can say $y \in \Bbb Z$, but if you are being formal and operating in $\Bbb R$ you can't identify the integers within $\Bbb R$.